# How to filter out items that are in a list of a list?

Tags: c#, linq

I am a little puzzled to how I can add items depending on the value that is in a list of a list.

I have these models

```
public class ItemsModel
{
    public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class OrdersModel
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public List<ItemsModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public class OrderResultModel
{
    public List<OrdersModel> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

**Question**

I need to add all orders from an api, but add Items that has SKU only ending with "5".

How can I do this?

**How I tried it**

I have an API call to get all orders.. `List<OrdersModel> GetOrders()`.

Then I add the data like so:

```
 public ObservableCollection<OrdersModel> Orders { get; private set; }

...

Orders = new ObservableCollection<OrdersModel>();

foreach (var item in GetOrders())
{
    Orders.Add(item);
}
```

Here is how I tried to add values with SKU ending with 5:

```
var list = GetOrders().Where(x => x.Items.Any(i => i.Sku.EndsWith("5")));

foreach (var item in list)
{
    Orders.Add(item);
}
```

**Problem**

This still shows me all values.. why? And how I can correct it?

Comment: add `ToList()` to your lambda expression: `var list = GetOrders().Where(x => x.Items.Any(i => i.Sku.EndsWith("5"))).ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(var order in GetOrders())
{
    order.Items = order.Items.Where(i => i.Sku.EndsWith("5")).ToList();
    Orders.Add(order);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's showing you all the value because `Any()` will evaluate to true if any of List of ItemsModels ends with 5.
you should filter on the list first something like

```
var filteredItems =  orders.Items.Where(i => i.sku.EndsWith("5"))
```